# Apache2 - How to configure Apache to automatically for ltd2

Tags: apache

How to configure Apache to automatically for ltd2

File /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName %-3.0.%-2.0.localhost
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/%-3.0.%-2.0/www
</VirtualHost>
```

File /var/www/localhost/foo/www/index.html

File /var/www/localhost/bar/www/index.html

Url http://foo.localhost

Url http://bar.localhost

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by ltd2? What exactly do you want your apache to do? Map the URLs you gave us to the files you named?

Comment: When the URL: http://foo.localhost want to load a file from /var/www/localhost/foo/index.html, When the URL: http://bar.localhost want to load a file from /var/www/localhost/bar/index.html. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never dealt with mod_vhost_alias, this should do it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirutalDocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you enable `Options +Indexes` somwhere in your config (you can do that inside the VirtualHost containers) to get the index.html when no file is specified. And, of course, make sure you actually use VirtualHosts (= make sure you have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` somewhere)

Comment: URL: http://localhost - loading data in /var/www/localhost/index.html - OK. URL: http://aaa.localhost - loading data in /var/www/localhost/aaa/index.html - Server Not Found :-(

Comment: Oh. Yes. But that's not an Apache problem. Your computer is just unable to resolve `aaa.localhost` to an IP, as there are no DNS servers for localhost. You have to enter the IP for that manually in your host file.